# How do we learn a subject which we know nothing about?

Tags: learning-methods

Recently I wanted to report on a certain social issue which was going on in my community. The problem I encountered was that there was a mass load of information and I didn't understand how to structure the story or how to assimilate and then put together the information from various sources that are available.

I no longer have a textbook at hand or a teacher to tell me how to approach learning this, so that makes it very difficult for me to know what to do. Any advice on how to be successful in such an unstructured / chaotic environment?

Comment: This is a site for philosophy rather than self-study help questions. A better place to ask would be [Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Draw a mind map. It is what I do to understand the problems of my clients. Then, you can explore each node in order. I'm voting this question to be closed, this is not the right site for it, sorry, not personal.

Answer (score 2):

You can start by pinning out the exact issue that is there. Remove any ambiguities related to the exact problem and have some kind of clarity about what is the core thing about the issue. You can also ensure some kind of clarity about who is getting affected by the issue and if it is being enforced by some authorities(could be senior members of the community) or if it a kind of peer pressure type of issue where there is no particular group enforcing but the mindset of everyone as a whole.

Then you can move to the "when" and "why" parts of the issue. It could be some kind of deep level conditioning in the people's minds or it could be because of some event that happened in the past. So I guess you can study approximately when this issue started to pop out what might be the possible reasons for it to happen.

Then you can suggest some kind of solution if you have one in mind or if you want to compile some already proposed solutions.

So I guess from a very high-level perspective it can be divided as such:

What

Who

By Whom

When

Why

Solution

Just sharing my thoughts here.

Answer (score 2):

This is more an academic question than a philosophical one, so there might be a better StackExchange for you to ask on.

Part of higher education is developing the skills to think and structure your own learning independently. There, that's the philosophy over with.

Broadly speaking I'd suggest you:

1 State the problem your community is facing.

2 Say what you think the cause/s is/are.

3 Explain why you think each of these is a cause.

At each stage, acknowledge the sources you are drawing on. You might want to include that in the text, or add footnotes, or a mixture of the two.

It takes a while to get the hang of this kind of thing, don't be too hard on yourself first time round!